# Difficulty passing a secure string to a system.data.odbc.odbcconnection object

Tags: powershell, db2, odbc

Im trying to pass a secure string to an odbc connection object to save me from passing a plain password over a network but cant quite figure it out. See the current iteration of my script below.

```
$encryptedPassword = Get-Content "<encrypted password.txt>"  

$runPassword = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR((ConvertTo-SecureString $encryptedPassword)))
$Db2Connection = new-object system.data.odbc.odbcconnection
$Db2Connection.connectionstring = "DSN=<dsn>;Userid=<user>;Password=$runPassword"
$Db2Connection.open()
$SqlQuery = @"
SELECT *
FROM <database>.<table>
"@

$SqlCmd = New-Object system.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($SqlQuery,$Db2Connection)
$DataAdapter = New-Object system.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter($SqlCmd)
$DataTable = New-Object system.Data.datatable
$RowCount = $DataAdapter.fill($DataTable)

$DataAdapter = new-object System.Data.odbc.odbcDataAdapter($SqlCmd) 
$DataSet = new-object System.Data.DataSet 
$DataAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$result = $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[4]
$result
```

As you can see, while i have encryption at rest the credentials will be handled in clear text using the following.

```
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR((ConvertTo-SecureString $encryptedPassword)))
```

Any thoughts or recommendations would be appreciated

Comment: Which Db2 driver are you using?  (i.e. from which vendor, and what is its exact version?).   IBM drivers support encrypted passwords on the network as long as the Db2-server authentication setup is correctly configured, and the encryption of the password is done by the Db2-client on the workstation invisibly to the application.

Comment: Using proprietary IBM drivers built for our hardware. I cant confirm too many details, id initially put some effort into what you are suggesting but i came across so many odd infrastructure problems i couldn't explain so i settled with an odbc which worked after a small amount. Its a fair point though, if there is no way for me to parse secure credentials via odbc i may have to go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using an IBM-supplied Db2-driver, it is the Db2-driver itself that handles encrypting the password before transmission.

The Db2-driver does this encrypting transparently to the application, and the application gives the plain-text password to the Db2-driver which encrypts is before transmission.  The Db2-server platform (Z/OS, i-series,  Linux/Unix/Windows) determines the configuration details for encrypted passwords.

So the application cannot supply an already-encrpyted password to Db2-driver.

Such transparent password-encryption requires correct **configuration** of the Db2-server authentication setup, and a suitable (meaning: recent and patch-maintained) Db2-driver at the workstations. Db2-clients also support data-encryption in transit in addition to password encryption, but that is a different matter.

As part of the connection attempt, the Db2-driver will obtain from the Db2-server the names of available encryption algorithms the Db2-server can support, and the Db2-client chooses (by default) the most secure algorithm that it can perform that is also available on the Db2-server. You can influence this choice by further configuration as documented in the Db2-Knowledge-Centre.

You can also write your own security-related plugins, if you have special requirements.